# Can't login to my acount Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

My Ubuntu worked well until yesterday when I installed some software (learning locker) in my machine.

After that, I got an error message:

> The volume "Filesystem root" has only 0 bytes of space remaining.

Since then, I can not log in to my account. When I enter the password, my system tries to start, but after 3 seconds, the system returns to the authentication page. I rebooted my several machine once without success.

How can I solve it?

[image: Error message]

Comment: If your $HOME (/home/user) account has 0 bytes free; the gui can't create its [needed temporary] work files and the login will fail, you'll be returned to the login screen (just as you describe).  I'd switch to a terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) and login there (terms don't need temporary work space), delete some stuff to create the required space so you can re-login [with gui].

Comment: @guiverc Thank you very much for your help, it works !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your $HOME (`/home/user` or home directory) account has **0 bytes free**; the GUI can't create its [needed temporary] work files and the login will fail. When it can't create these files, you are returned to the login screen (just as you describe).

The fastest fix (in my opinion) is to switch to a [pseudo] terminal (use ctrl+alt+f4 for example) and login there using your default username/passwd.
 Terminals don't require the temporary files so login will succeed.  Then remove/delete some unnecessary stuff so as to create the required space, and you will discover on switching back to gui you can login normally.